# How to view a multi-lined string on browser which is fetched from Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a pastebin type of thing.
I have got my php code

```
<?php    
  printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Xdev - CodeShare</title>
</head>

<form method="post" action="cslink.php">
        <textarea cols="100" rows="20" name="textbox"></textarea> 
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
</form>
```

and my php file to store it in my mysql database

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
// Connecting to the MySQL database
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$username = $_POST['textbox'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `text` (`id`, `text` ) VALUES (NULL, '$username' );";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

and my view file (also in php)

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM text WHERE id = 3';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id = $row['id'];
$text = $row['text'];

echo "id: " . $id . "<br/>";
echo "text: " . $text . "<br/>";
echo $text;
}

?>
```

**So if I type in:**

```
hello 
world 
testing
```

(each on a separate line)

It will show up as this: `hello world testing` - all in a  single line

I want to know if I can and how to output it as separate lines

Comment: P.S. ***Please*** don't actually use this code.  It's very unsafe.  Look into using MySQLi (or PDO) instead and also using prepared statements.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.[Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: [**nl2br()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)????

Comment: Try using PHP's `nl2br()` function.  Browsers will collapse excess whitespace and newlines.

Comment: i know this is unsecure but it is used for the purpose for the question. i will change it after

Comment: Wrap your view in pre tag <pre> $output </pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @itachi mentioned, nl2br should solve this problem.